# How to open Uri in Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, uri, file-access

How do I open a file by Uri with the Android NDK?

```
fopen(uri);
```

Trying fopen on the Uri obviously fails.

Comment: I see no uri to begin with.

Comment: Edited the question. fopen wont work with uri. How to I use a uri to open a file in the ndk?